# Angular acquiring undefined as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular and what I'm encountering now is something that I'm not able to understand.
I'm passing data between pages on url using $routeParams. In the first page I have in the url this kind of data: 
`localhost/server/documentList/?agentId=18& date=Tue%20Nov%2001%202016%2000:00:00%20GMT%2B0100%20(Central%20Europe%20Standard%20Time)`
In the receiving page I'm acquiring the data like this:

```
$scope.filter.date= $routeParams.date;
$scope.filter.agentId= $routeParams.agentId;
```

and using the data acquired to do a call to the server. If the url was 
`localhost/server/documentList/?agentId=undefined&date=undefined`
the data is correctly interpreted as undefined so I receive null.

**The Problem:**

If from this page go to another one, and then go back using the browser previous button, the data this time will be acquired as string, so I will have agentId="undefined" instead of agentId = undefined. Same with the date I will have the date acquired as string instead of date.

Can someone explain this? And give me a proper solution?

**EDIT**

I'm using this code to reach the first page

```
$location.path(path).search(
                {

                    "date": $scope.filter.date,
                    "agentId": $scope.filter.agentId
                });
```

So if $scope.filter.date is undefined, it is passed as undefined. Am I using this in the wrong way? How can I have date not present in the url if `$scope.filter.date` is undefined?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're doing, but values passed in a querystring will always be strings, there's no way they will be interpreted as actually being `undefined` ?

Comment: If the variables are undefined they should not be passed as undefined in the first place, they should just miss from the query string.

Comment: @RobertoLonardi yeah i got it, now why the first time is interpreted correctly as a null or undefined value, and the second as a string?

Comment: @RobertoLonardi with the date the problem apply when it's valorized, so the problem persist.

Comment: Why you add an object with the same keys as the filter under $scope? can't you use directly the filter? I mean like this: `$location.path(path).search($scope.filter);`
You avoid the creation of a new object just for passing the values, plus if date is not present is not passed because is not present in filter.